# Deleting files takes orders of magnitude longer when using a UNC path as opposed to a mapped drive

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-8

This is a strange one.  I have a folder structure which looks like this:

```
Folder A
  File
  Folder B
    File x2
    Folder C
      File x4
      Folder D
        File
        Folder E
          Folder F
            File
```

I'm working on a small data utility which will, among other things, delete these folders from file to time. The test data that I am working with is very small; the entire directory contains 186KB of data.

I have noticed that, most of the time, delete operations of the entire directory are taking 15-18 minutes, which is ridiculous. After futzing around with no general idea of what the problem could be, I replaced the paths in the form of:

```
Directory.Delete(@"\\server\share\FolderA", true);
```

With the mapped drive equivalent:

```
Directory.Delete(@"X:\FolderA", true);
```

All of a sudden, no issue.  Completely unreproducible with the mapped drive.  I next tried the IP address and the issue persisted.

I should note that this doesn't happen *ever* time, but on the order of ~90% when using a UNC path.  Again, never happens with the mapped drive notation.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this?  The only thing I can think of is the per-request authentication happening when I use the UNC path, but it's hard to believe that would case the delete to take 15 minutes.

EDIT: This is obviously not a dupe of the linked thread.  This has to do with *massive* slowdown accessing the same remote resource via a UNC path versus a mapped drive.  No resources are local and the performance difference is unreasonable.

Comment: @rmc00: It's not a dupe of that question.  Please read the post before marking as a dupe

Comment: I'd guess that using a mapped drive allows Windows to reused a cached connection or session.

Comment: Environmental issue of course, [this page](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=107677) is typical.  CAS doesn't make this any faster.  Talk to the people at serverfault.com, they troubleshoot this kind of stuff for a living.

Comment: @SLaks: Agreed, though it's the magnitude of the difference that I don't understand.  We're talking about ~200KB and a few folders taking 15+ minutes to delete.  The mapped version takes milliseconds.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks, good suggestion.

Comment: Does it happen on the same UNC path twice in a row?  Is DFS involved?  Have you looked at what is going across the wire in Wireshark/Message Analyzer?